# Adding data to the dictionary

Tags: python, function, loops

I have a function that loops through a database. And it writes the result to a dictionary. But it doesn't work. Each loop doesn't write new data into the dictionary, but overwrites the previous ones. How may I fix the error in my code?

A fragment of my code:

```
if x is not None:
    for key, value in qur_list.items():
        with conn.cursor() as cursor:
            sql = f"""
                  SELECT DISTINCT {value};
                  """
            cursor.execute(sql)
            result = {}
            for fnc in cursor.fetchall():
                if fnc[0] in result.fromkeys([0], [1]):
                    result[fnc[0]].append(fnc[1])
                else:
                    result[fnc[0]] = fnc[1]
```

Comment: On your else you replace and not append as you do on the if.

Answer (score 0):

just move `result = {}` outside of `for` loop. Also `fnc[0]` should be unique. Think how to define unique key in dictionary